# HighChart - accessing series data by category name

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The question is simple. How do I programmatically edit data series which corresponds to `desired_category_name` [in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6p45gwx/) ?

```
$(function() {

  var chart, x,
    btnRemove = $('#remove'),
    btnAdd = $('#add'),
    btnEdit = $('#edit');
  x = 10;
  btnAdd.click(function() {
    chart.series[0].addPoint(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)); // Return random integer between 1 and 10.
  });

  btnEdit.click(function() {

    desired_category_name = 'USA'
      // Do something like   chart.series[0].data[i].update(x += 10);

  });

  btnRemove.click(function() {
    if (chart.series[0].points[0]) {
      chart.series[0].points[0].remove();
    }
  });

  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
      text: 'No data in pie chart'
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Random data',
      data: [
        ['USA', 1],
        ['Europe', 2]
      ]
    }]
  });

  chart = $('#container').highcharts();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access series data with this - it has an array of points:

```
  chart.series[0]
```

You can modify point with this:

```
  chart.series[0].data[0].update( _new_value_ )
```

Each point has an attribute "name" that corresponds to category.

```
  chart.series[0].data[0].name // USA
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nhm9cjc/

```
 $('#edit').click(function() {

    desired_category_name = 'USA';
      // Do something like   chart.series[0].data[i].update(x += 10);
      console.log(chart.series[0].data.length)
      for(var i = 0; i< chart.series[0].data.length; i++){

         if(chart.series[0].data[i].name===desired_category_name){
            chart.series[0].data[i].update(10);
         }
      }


  });
```

Comment: Didn't get your point. So how do I get the index of the desired data? Can you demonstrate this in jsfiddle?

Comment: added link to jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks for that Vladimir. I figured it out myself ) A bit off-topic. Do you think it is better to grab a new JSON from server and use setData method to update graph, or do it client side instead ?

Comment: I think, it really depends on your application. In general, for a larger applications you should have some MVC structure, and chart update should be operating on the model data. In this respect, from rendering point of view, it should not make much of a difference. But you may want to consider other factors, such as, what is the extra load on the server, what is easier to maintain in the long run, etc.